# Is there any way to create one image(Instead of 4 with different resolutions ldpi,mdpi,hdpi and xhdpi) and use for all the android device resolutions?

Tags: android

Is there any way to create one image(Instead of 4 with different resolutions ldpi,mdpi,hdpi and xhdpi) and use it for all the android device resolutions?

Comment: You may also find drawables-nodpi useful.  Often overlooked...

Comment: Sorry, I'm just a bit curious. Why would you want or need that? Are you constricted in any way by app size?

Comment: Not restricted by app size, but wanted to view the image based on device resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one image for all, the larger one would be better for quality, android will automatically resize them, however the reason you give the different sizes is to save time and memory. You don't want to be doing this every single time the application loads, because it will slow things down, it might not be noticeable to you, but to slower devices it might be.

Since mdpi, or medium density is the basis for all the others I would create one of them and use it for all, but it might not look to good on all devices.

In short your application would be better if you created all the sizes.

You could also look at 9 patches if you want.

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions. I have tried using mdpi for all the densities but it's disturbing the layout. Anyways, need to try with 9 patch images.

Answer (score 0):

Just create one (e.g. medium density/mdpi) and ommit the others. Android will use the closest that fits and scale it if required.

If you want a quote from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

> By default, Android scales your bitmap drawables (.png, .jpg, and .gif files) and Nine-Patch drawables (.9.png files) so that they render at the appropriate physical size on each device. For example, if your application provides bitmap drawables only for the baseline, medium screen density (mdpi), then the system scales them up when on a high-density screen, and scales them down when on a low-density screen. This scaling can cause artifacts in the bitmaps. To ensure your bitmaps look their best, you should include alternative versions at different resolutions for different screen densities.
>
> The configuration qualifiers you can use for density-specific resources are ldpi (low), mdpi (medium), hdpi (high), and xhdpi (extra high). For example, bitmaps for high-density screens should go in drawable-hdpi/.

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions. I have tried using mdpi for all the densities but it's disturbing the layout. Anyways, need to try with 9 patch images.

Comment: Sounds like you might have to define the dimensions of the control a different way. Are you using px or dp for example?

Comment: I'm using dp's. But, not interested to specify 30dp and 40dp for example. Wanted to wrap content an imageview to look good in all the screens.

Comment: Would be helpful for you to provide some image of the actual issue/layout if possible. Even if you replace your images/texts with some dummy stuff to not break any NDA or whatever.